# Make word hyperlinks independent of drive letter

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I have a word document with lots of hyperlinks to different files on my PC. The problem occured when some of those files were relocated. Hyperlinks stopped working. I decided to place all files in a separate folder called "files" in the same directory as my word document.

But again one problem came. My drive became full and i had to change location of my word document.

Again my hyperlinks stopped working because drive letter changed.

Please suggest how this can be fixed? I want my links to be immune to any change in drive letter. I will maintain the directory structure but drive letter may change like suppose i put my document in c: like c:\test.doc and all files in c:\files\ but for some reason if i change the drive letter like f:\test.doc and f:\files\ in this case the links should work.

How this can be achieved?"

Comment: See Paul Edstein (macropod)'s work on relative file paths to external files in fields. (Hyperlinks, in Word, are fields.) http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do that, depends on what you prefer.

Here is one: define an environment variable, like `%MyFiles%=D:\wherever\subdir\here\`, and use that one inside the links.

Another one: define an extra drive letter, like `M:` or `T:` - you have the whole alphabet to chose from - that points to your directory (in Explorer), and use that drive letter.